# How to find the longest method/class in solution?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, code-analysis

For code analysis goals I want to know some interesting statistics about my project. I.e. number of classes, methods, the longest class, the longest method etc etc. Is there any nice tool for this or maybe extension for Visual Studio?

I looked at codecity, but it can analyze only MSE files which I don't have and has the worst interface I've seen for the past 5 years, but functionality nearly what I need.

Comment: Recently started looking at open cover with report generator, have you taken a look at these?

Comment: The [Redgate Performance Pack](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/dotnet-tool-collections/dotnet-performance-pack/) is good for this, it's pricey but has a free trial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To provide more info concerning the tool [NDepend](http://www.NDepend.com) that P.Brian.Mackey mentioned, indeed the tool provides the [weight code metrics](http://www.ndepend.com/Metrics.aspx) you are looking for. *(Disclaimer: I am a developer working on this tool)*.

With NDepend you can query with C# LINQ queries, the code metrics, and see the code elements matched. All this is integrated in Visual Studio.

[image: Big Classes with NDepend]

The tool comes also with a [code metric view](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_Treemap.aspx), that is actually a [treemap view](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping). Rectangles on the treemap represents code elements (here *methods*) and the area of a rectangle is proportional to the code metric selected (here *# lines of code per method*). Code elements matched by the C# LINQ query are shown in blue on the treemap.

[image: Treemap metric view]

Answer (score 11):

Visual Studio has such a function in *Analyze* => *Calculate Code Metrics*. Among other things, it shows the LoC for each namespace which can be split down to method level. It doesn't make any fancy diagrams, but for pure interest it is sufficient.

[image]

Comment: That is only available in [Premium or Ultimate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385908.aspx) editions, however.

Comment: These days this is available in the Professional edition of Visual Studio

Comment: Also available in Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022

Answer (score 3):

"Measuring code by weight" is generally a bad idea.  I obtain meaningful code metrics with tools such as [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/).

Comment: I'm not saying that this is the only thing how I define code quality, but one of these. I believe that there is no *good* method that has one thousand lines in it.

Comment: @VitaliiKorsakov - Agreed.  However, Cyclomatic Complexity covers the same ground with more meaning.